# Extract device unique id with javascript in both browser and react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uuid, child-process

I need to calculate a device unique id (for example a combination of device mac address, cpu id, etc) in both web browser and react native app.

Also, it needs to be same on a single device's browser an installed react-native app.

I've tried following library [node-machine-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-machine-id), it works fine on the browser but the problem is react native because it needs to use `child_process` but `child_process` is not available on react native (as I know, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7170).

Answer (score 0):

You cant have an universal Device Unique ID on web browser.

You could achieve this by using a randomly generated string (for example based on timestamp) saved in the local storage on web browser :

```
localStorage.setItem('deviceId', uniqueRandomString)
```

and async storage on react-native:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:deviceId', uniqueRandomString);
```

Then read it and send to server.